# How do you complete the Switcharoo and Decisions challenges?

Tags: hero-academy

How do you complete the **Switcharoo** challenge in Meet the Council and the **Decisions** challenge in Meet the Dwarves?

Answer (score 1):

**Switcharoo** involves a lot of swapping places with the Ninja in order to take out the three enemy units.

- First Turn - Swap the Ninja and Archer.
- Second Turn - Use the Ninja to attack the Necromancer.
- Third Turn - Swap the Ninja and Wizard.
- Fourth Turn - Use the Wizard to attack the Necromancer - his bolt will hit all three units and knock out the top Necromancer and the phantom.
- Fifth Turn - Use the Archer to attack the bottom Necromancer.

**Decisions** is actually quite simple.  Move the Grenadier up two squares (immediately to the right of the Paladin).  Scroll him and attack the Knight.  Attack the Knight two more times - the splash damage will take out all the other units.

Comment: @user29389 - No problem.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: How do you beat the decisions challenge!? That strategy does not work. Leaves the 4 guys around the Knight at very low health but not dead.

Comment: The solution to Decisions requires that the grenadier be moved beside the paladin in order to gain the small attack boost from the paladin.  Moving the grenadier anywhere else results in the situation you describe.